# \ref command only works for 1 out of 2 tables (overleaf)

Tags: cross-referencing, xr-hyper

I have two files, see below (main_text.tex and supplemental_text.tex, respectively). Output is "1 ??". Why is there not a 2 in place of the question marks?

I compiled both documents multiple times from scratch. This is the error I get: {@firstoffive }\fi  \ref {table:ICC} \end {document}
! File ended while scanning use of \Hy@setref@link.

Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}
% Add cross-referencing between different files 
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
% add hyper-references
\externaldocument{supplemental_text}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \ref{table:MDES}
    \ref{table:ICC}
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{A.} \label{table:MDES}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{B.} \label{table:ICC}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have something very strange going on if one `xr` reference is appearing correctly but not the other.  With your code in Overleaf I do not get any cross-referencing between files, however this is to be expected with Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf#How_to_use_xr_on_Overleaf) do you already have a `latexmkrc` file in your project?

Comment: I'm impressed, you made a really good example. The example works fine in a current tex system, but if your system is older you should load hyperref in both documents to avoid errors.

Comment: have you run latex on supplemental_text.tex since adding the second table?

Comment: Thank you, Everyone! @Dai adding the latexmkrc file worked. I did so before (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf#Code_for_latexmkrc) but I also added the helper code to my file which apparently was not needed. In addition, I now deleted all aux files.